# oozie workflow to grant 777 permission on hive table ie directories

Tags: hadoop, hive, bigdata, oozie

I wanted to grant 777 permission to hive directories using OOzie workflow.
do we have any xml tags which will be used directly
FYI I am using Hadoop , Ambari , HUE.

Comment: No, there is no Action to change HDFS attributes. Because there should be no need for that: ad hoc access **rules** can be defined, once and for all, via HDFS ACLs _(although there is a bug in Hadoop 2.x)_ or Ranger/Sentry policies.

Comment: Could you please let me know how to define those ad hoc rules to all users for particular directory inside /apps/hive/warehouse/directory_name.db

Comment: If your cluster has Sentry or Ranger installed then just read the docs! Otherwise, HDFS uses the same concept and syntax of "POSIX ACLs" as local Linux file systems, just read a tutorial and experiment!